# Getting error while calling google map api & google url shorten api in same program

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, url, google-maps-api-3

So I've written a program where I'm passing data to iframe through url. But as the url can be huge(IE supports only 2083 characters)  I'm using google url shorten api to shorten the url & then sending the url as an argument. Later we will fetch the longUrl using the short url and extract the actual data.

But the problem is calling two api in same program.

Below is a simple code where I'm fetching the long url from google then initializing the map. As according to my logic first we will extract data from long url and then we will point the markers, we can not initialize the map before calling the Google shorten url api.

Code-

```
<html>
<head>
</head> 
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script>
function makeURLShortenApiCall(){
var shortUrl="";
gapi.client.setApiKey('AIzaSyDQo3yvYTgw7pdfGTRz6zanq41rhymA-N8');
gapi.client.load('urlshortener', 'v1',function(){

var shortUrl="http://goo.gl/AWGcY4";

    var request = gapi.client.urlshortener.url.get({
      'shortUrl': shortUrl,
    'projection':'FULL'
    });
    request.execute(function(response) 
    {

        if(response.longUrl!= null)
        {
            console.log(response.longUrl);
            initialize();
        }
        else
        {
            alert("error: "+response.error);
        }

    });

});
}
</script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=makeURLShortenApiCall"></script>
<script>
function initialize() {
  var mapProp = {
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
    zoom:5,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("Map"),mapProp);
}
</script>
<body>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;" class="absolute"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

It's giving some error like-

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null
```

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Sounds like the "map" iframe hasn't been rendered when the javascript is executing.  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Sorry but this problem has been resolved. it was because the id didn't match.

Comment: If you solved the problem, please, make an answer with the solution and mark it as valid -or- delete the question. @AnuragChakraborty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I found the problem.

It was because

```
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("Map"),mapProp);
```

Id `Map` didn't match with `div id` `googleMap`

```
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;" class="absolute"></div>
```

Anyway thanks for helping.